# Converting A Shell cURL Command To PHP

Tags: php, shell, curl

I'm hoping someone might be able to help me with a small cURL test that I am doing.  In Terminal, I am able to successfully get a response by doing the following;

`curl -u domain\\user:password https://server.whatever.com/EWS/Services.wsdl`

I am trying to convert this to work on PHP, using the following;

```
    $ch = curl_init(); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://server.whatever.com/EWS/Services.wsdl');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'domain\\user:password');

    $output = curl_exec($ch); 

    $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    echo "Output: $output<br>";
    echo "Status code: $status_code<br>";

    curl_close($ch);
```

Sadly, this does not seem yield any response (output and always blank and status code is always 0).  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Status code 0 generally means that it couldn't connect. Have you tried checking the output of `curl_error($ch)`?

Comment: Execllent suggestion!  It ended up being a SSL certificate issue.  I added the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0` option and now I'm working.  Thank you!